# Page views for questions after answers have been given

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I sometimes wonder how many page views there have been on a question *after* a particular answer has been given.

Could the page views counter could be a hyperlink that opens a summary window that lists page views by answer since that answer was given? Would anyone else find this useful / interesting?

Comment: The views count is plain number at the moment, I remember seeing the devs talking about that at some point. As result what you ask for is not possible without major change.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I disagree. I want to know the number of views after each question has been posted, not a binned count of views across time. Similar, but not the same. However it does kinda answer my question. Data is not stored, so a no-go.

Comment: @SimonO101: The *answer* is going to be exactly the same: no, that information is not available, and the devs are not keen on adding any feature that'd require them to retain finer-grained view information.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I realise that, which is exactly what I said in my comment above?!!

Comment: @SimonO101: I know you did; but you also said you disagree it's a dupe; I am reiterating why I feel this is a dupe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair enough.